# Adding a dimmer switch

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I bought a dimmer switch that is digital and it is a remote switch. Come to find out you need a master switch to run two dimmer switches to one light. The only way to get the master switch is to buy the combo kit. $60 + dollars and I already have a remote switch. Bought a single pole paddle switch and it works. (Paddle switch doesn't have a dimmer). The remote switch with the dimmer does not work. Are the two switches compatible?

Comment: Without brand/model our guess is probably less accurate than yours.  I'm going with "sure, why not?".

Comment: Can you provide make/model information?

Comment: Definitely needs more information, but I'm going to say "no" - simple single-pole paddle switches are unlikely to be compatible with 3-way digital dimmer switches. Ideally you need proper 3-way (or 4-way?) pre-existing switch wiring, possibly also including neutral in at least one of the switch boxes. The manufacturers of the switches will tell you how to install and use them properly - it's not only difficult to ignore their instructions and set it up yourself, it could be dangerous and violates the safety ratings.

Comment: Warning, the dimmer also has to be compatible with the light, especially if its LED.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 switches controlling one light, most likely you have a "3-way" as the Americans call it.

In a 3-way wiring topology, you do not get to choose the location of the smart switch/dimmer.  That is dictated to you by the wiring in the walls.

So the usual problem in cases like yours is that you are trying to install the smart switch/dimmer in the wrong location.

Sometimes the arrangement is a "switch loop" with power to the lamp, and you have no ability to install a smart switch or dimmer which requires neutral.   In that case, your option is to add /3 cable between lamp and the switch the lamp is cabled to.   Or rearrange the wiring so power supply comes from a switch.